# Does AppEngine's datastore.Get() not verify the namespace of the requested key?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using namespaces with the datastore in go-appengine, roughly as follows:

```
func getThing() *Thing {
  nctx := appengine.Namespace(ctx, "whatever")

  thing := Thing{}
  key, err := datastore.Get(nctx, key, &thing)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return thing, nil
}
```

Simple enough, right? Unfortunately, if it turns out that if nctx's namespace doesn't match the key's, it happily fetches the object anyway. And AFAICT, there's no way to manually get at the key's 'namespace' field to verify it manually. This matters for our app, because we have keys coming from a web client, which can in some edge cases be associated with the wrong namespace.

OTOH, if I do a **query** using `Thing`'s key as an ancestor, the datastore (appropriately) returns an error because of the namespace mismatch between the ancestor's namespace and that of the context (of the form `query namespace is 'bar' but ancestor namespace is 'foo'`).

Am I missing something about the intended constraints on datastore fetches/queries and namespaces, or does this just sound like a bug?

Comment: But while I don't know GO lang, solution in python perhaps will be helpful for you: in python you can check namespace using method Key.namespace(): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass - maybe in GO we need wait for it :)

Comment: Using namespaces as an access control mechanism (which it sounds like you are doing) is inviting trouble. It would be reasonable to file a feature request for a Namespace method on *datastore.Key, but if you can't trust the key then perhaps you should be building it up from validated data instead.

Comment: It seems crazy that the essential internal field Namespace is available in Python and Java... and not in Go. I think I just lost 4 hours working one something that is simply impossible because of this limitation.

Comment: UPDATE: a public accessor datastore.Key.Namespace() has been added in sdk 1.9.4 : http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10813 . It is already available on GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're passing around encoded keys, rather than just their IDs? If you create the key using `datastore.NewKey` then the context passed to that will set the namespace of the key (unless there's also a parent, in which case *its* namespace will be used).

With respect to the intention, this behaviour is equivalent to the python API - a key created from an urlsafe string can be fetched while a different namespace is set on the `namespace_mananger`, but the currently-set namespace is used if you create a key by specifying just the kind and id.

Having a getter for the namespace would be good though, so you could at least verify after unserializing...

Comment: [Would have responded sooner, but didn't get the notification for some reason.]

This makes a kind of sense -- I'm still a little surprised about the ability to fetch from an encoded key using an appengine.Context with the wrong namespace set, but we've just switched away from using encoded keys anyway, so the problem's now obviated.

For anyone else reading this -- it feels natural to use encoded keys when you first start using the datastore, but I strongly suggest using ids instead, and reconstructing datastore.Key objects on the server. Everything works more naturally that way.